# Faster processing of large files

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, data-processing

```
//string filename = "123.txt";
foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(pathToDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
using (var fsIn = new FileStream(files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var fsOut = new FileStream($"{files}.crypt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
using (var aes = Aes.Create())
using (var enc = aes.CreateEncryptor(new byte[16] /* key */, new byte[16] /* vector */))
using (var cs = new CryptoStream(fsIn, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    cs.CopyTo(fsOut);
```

It takes a long time to process large files, read that there is a [MemoryMappedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) method that can process large files, tell me how you can use it in the code above ??

Comment: How long does it take? Which part of the code is taking time? Does processing the files in parallel help? Does `EnumerateFiles` help?

Answer (score 2):

A *MemoryMappedFile* is not really going to do much for you unless you need it all in memory at once.

Your bottle-neck is likely *IO* not the *CPU*, as such I would look to playing with the `BufferSize` and setting `SequentialScan` on the `FileStream`s which may help reading and writing in larger chunks to the internal buffer (especially for modern SSDs), and better optimizing the OS file cache (respectively)

[FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare, Int32, FileOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_IO_FileOptions_)

> **bufferSize**
>
> A positive Int32 value greater than 0 indicating the buffer size. The
> default buffer size is 4096.

[FileOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions?view=netcore-3.1)

> **SequentialScan**
>
> Indicates that the file is to be accessed sequentially from beginning
> to end. The system can use this as a hint to optimize file caching. If
> an application moves the file pointer for random access, optimum
> caching may not occur; however, correct operation is still guaranteed.
> Specifying this flag can increase performance in some cases.

Also note, that reading and writing files and processing them in parallel may work to a certain extent (though usually won't all that much if you are waiting on *IO*), it really depends on how well your device controller deals with queue-depth and how much *bottle-neck* is caused by the CPU. But once again you will need to play with it and its *degrees of parallelism* for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try Nugetting "System.Reactive"? Add in the reference to `System.Reactive.linq` and then try this:

```
var query =
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(pathToDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany(files =>
            Observable.Using(() => new FileStream(files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), fsIn =>
                Observable.Using(() => new FileStream($"{files}.crypt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write), fsOut =>
                    Observable.Using(() => Aes.Create(), aes =>
                        Observable.Using(() => aes.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey: new byte[16], rgbIV: new byte[16]), enc =>
                            Observable.Using(() => new CryptoStream(fsIn, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Read), cs => Observable.FromAsync(() => cs.CopyToAsync(fsOut))))))));
                            
query.ToArray().Wait();
```

If that runs faster then you have some benefit from parallel processing. If not then you are IO bound and running parallel isn't going to help.

In any case, I don't see where memory mapped files will help.

Comment: Nice work. If you have a test set up, just curious what happens if you set a larger buffer size (if ssd, 10k or something) and the FileModeOptions to sequential (with your parallel test)

Comment: @MichaelRandall - I tried changing the settings but couldn't get anything other than 16 & 16 to run - also could find where to set the mode to sequential?

Comment: sequential can be set in this constructor in the end options  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_IO_FileOptions_ all good though, was just curious